# Android appbar/branding bar color not changing on custom theme switch in API 24,25(Nougat) when in task switching mode

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three themes defined in my app as follows

```
<style name="Theme.ThemeA" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ThemeB" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_green</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_green</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ThemeC" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_red</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

If you see the below screenshots from an emulator API level 23 on switching to different themes, in the **task switching mode**, the appbar/branding bar color changes based on colorPrimary set in the theme.

[image: API level 23 - On selected Theme A app bar color is blue]
[image: API level 23 - On selected Theme B app bar color is green]

However, on a nougat device i.e. API levels 24 and 25 on switching theme, the appbar/branding bar color continues to use colorPrimary from ThemeA irrespective of seletected them. See below screenshot
[image: API Level 25 - On selecting Theme B]

Another [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ejX3s) to show the task switcher view in two emulators

Since I can't share the actual source code, I quickly put together a sample project to show the problem. I have hosted this sample project on google drive Link : [Source code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B51rW517j922c3FicEJXcmpPRk0)

Can anyone please help me in solving this? Is there any work around to this
problem?

Comment: Just tried on API25 and it works fine for me. Maybe you should try to post a complete example and specify how do you "switch the theme". Also, what happen if you delete the ThemeA?

Comment: I tried your code before the onCreate of a BaseActivity, it's working for me on API 25. But I don't fully understand the scenario, what is the reason to don't set the theme at application level?

Comment: @LuigiPapino I have edited my question to be in more detail and posted a link to the a sample source code which shows the problem.

Comment: [Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3UUo7gdGILbYURBWXA2cU50eWc/view?usp=sharing)
I wasn't able to import your project, so I did it manually, and it's working for me. I tried it also on a real device Pixel XL API 25.
So, I don't know, your code looks fine for me. Here the [Github](https://github.com/LuigiPapino/StackOverfowColorPrimary) so you can try to run it

Comment: @LuigiPapino Thank you for importing the project and posting on git hub. If you see the screenshot here http://imgur.com/a/ejX3s , the issue i'm trying to solve is when you see the appbar/branding bar in the task switcher mode. The bar color changes based on colorPrimary set in the theme for API>=21 & API < 24. For API >= 24 the branding bar color continues to use colorPrimary from theme A even on switching to Theme B or Theme C . Let me know if you see this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139056/discussion-between-luigi-papino-and-santosh-v-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in Nougat something changed with tasks and TaskDescription, maybe for the multiwindow?

However you can force the bar color in the app switcher with this method that you can call after the `setTheme`

```
  private void setTaskDescription() {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorPrimary, typedValue, true);
    int color = typedValue.data;

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    ActivityManager.TaskDescription td = new ActivityManager.TaskDescription(null, bm, color);

    setTaskDescription(td);
    bm.recycle();
  }
```

The full explanation in this blog: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/polishing-your-Android-overview-screen-entry/